# Autocomplete not working for array methods in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

I am using RubyMine 2018.3. With the following, I didn't get suggestions for `new` after typing up to `ne`.

```
array1 = Array.new
```

With the following, I typed up to `pus`, and didn't get auto-complete suggestion for `push`.

```
array1.push("shivendra")
```

Similarly for `insert`, `pop`, and `delete_at`. I do not get auto-complete suggestion.

1. Is this issue happening only for me, or do others also face this issue?
2. How can I make auto-complete work? I am willing to use any gem file, other editor, or external library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have RubyMine 2018.3 too. I tried and it doesn't work for me either.

But I never use this way because in accordance with the codestyle [it is not recommended](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#literal-array-hash).

If you write `array1 = [` – RubyMine will autocomplete it.

After this if you write `array1.pu` – RubyMine will offer `push`.